# Valid image link is downloaded when open

Tags: html

I have an application. The backend returns the link to  a image. When i add that link inside

```html
<img alt="img" src="/path/to/image">
```

i get a broken image on UI, but if i take the src (link to the image) and put it in the url of the browser the browser sundently download the image, but not opening in the browser. Why the image is broken even with a valid URL? And why the browser download the image when i try to open it?

Comment: check if it works if you remove that first slash in the path?

Comment: @Sumithran the path starts witth `https://...`